# When using web3.js/Metamask on your website - how can you trust the data coming from your users?

Tags: web3js, metamask, security, ethereumjs

So let's say your user sends a transaction, your script gets the receipt (getTransactionReceipt), checks if everything is fine and then does something. Can't people just rewrite your scripts in developer console and send fake data?

For example:
Bob needs to pay 1 ETH. Can't he just fake his address (of someone who already paid you the same amount) or use someone's transaction id or maybe when at the end your JS sends data to your server to recheck the transaction he could send fake address/transaction id?

Comment: I have the same root question, different use case.  I want my user to be able to link his/her account on my site with their wallet.  However, what is to stop them from manipulating the JS that gets their wallet addr and sends it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user will be able to fake their public address for *read only* purposes (see  [impersonator](https://twitter.com/apoorvlathey/status/1429212169531396099)) but will never be able to fake a signature for a message or transaction.

I'm not actually sure what your use-case is, but you can safely bind an address to a certain user through a simple utility involving asymmetric encryption. If you have a frontend + backend architecture and you need to be sure the user has access to a certain address (public key), ask them to sign a message (frontend). The decryption of this message (backend) will succeed only if the user has access to the private key of that account, hence owns it.